# Python return values from one function to another in infinite loop

Tags: python, function, return, infinite-loop

Problem:

def tradingview(): is infite loop which should return two numbers

```
def tradingview():
        while True:           
                with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                        count_var_short = f.read().count('Exit Short    Open')
                        print('Current shorts open:',count_var_short)                            
                with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                        count_var_long = f.read().count('Exit Long    Open')
                        print('Current longs open:',count_var_long)                           
        return (count_var_short,count_var_long)


def target_balance(count_var_short,count_var_long):
        current_target = cur_price_VWAP['vwap'] * freebalance['BTC']['free']
        print ('current_target long',current_target * count_var_short)
        print ('current_target short',current_target * count_var_long)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Thread(target = tradingview).start()
        Thread(target = target_balance(count_var_short,count_var_long)).start()
```

This code gives error

```
Thread(target = target_balance(count_var_short,count_var_long)).start()
NameError: name 'count_var_short' is not defined
```

===============================================

i want `def tradingview():`   return two numbers

`count_var_short` and `count_var_long`

and use them in function

```
def target_balance(count_var_short,count_var_long):
```

i know i should read how return works, but i will very thankful if someone help me on my own code because it is much more understandable for me.

Comment: Why are you creating threads to execute functions? Do you understand that you can't have a return value until the first function completes? What is happening here?

Comment: Why do I see a `while True` loop without any exit or break statements? Do you want that infinite loop? The program will never reach the `return` statement.

Comment: Also, please don't link to off site code. That's the whole point of a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar. I hadn't even looked that far. That actually answers my question.

Comment: def tradingview(): is infite loop which should return two numbers

Comment: It will **never** return anything due to the infinite loop.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my comment about the whole code. We don't want or need to see it. What you already have is fine and I appreciate your dedication to completeness.

Comment: okay, i got it.

Comment: So i  want consctruction like this one:

Comment: While True:
print('Current shorts open:',count_var_short)                            
return (count_var_short)

Comment: print('Current longs open:',count_var_long)                            
return (count_var_short)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a function with a single return value, you are looking to create a generator, which `yield`s an expression, and then resumes execution.

You can rewrite `tradingview` to be an infinite generator:

```
def tradingview():
    while True:
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            count_var_short = f.read().count('Exit Short    Open')
            print('Current shorts open:',count_var_short)                            
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            count_var_long = f.read().count('Exit Long    Open')
            print('Current longs open:',count_var_long)                           
        yield count_var_short, count_var_long
```

The `yield` expression *inside* the loop will "return" the values you want before resuming execution. It will also turn `tradingview` from a regular function into a generator function, which returns the generator when called.

Now you can rewrite the code that calls `target_balance` to use the generator:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for count_var_short, count_var_long in tradingview():
        target_balance(count_var_short,count_var_long)
```

No need for strange threading behavior: Python has already supplied the behavior you need with generators. I suggest you read up on them (and the `yield` keyword in general).